# Adding a many-to-many view in EF6

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have an EDMX file which has both tables and views mapped from a SQL Server database.  I am trying to add a view named CourseCompany to the EDMX file which serves as a many-to-many connection between two other views.

By looking at another many-to-many association using tables as an example, these are the non-default value properties on the association I added:

- Association Set Name:   CourseCompany
- End1 Multiplicity:   * (Collection of Course)
- End1 Navigation Property:   Companies
- End2 Multiplicity:   * (Collection of Company)
- End 2 Navigation Property:   Courses
- Name:   CourseCompany

But doing this produces this compile error:

**Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - CourseCompany**

I made sure the views that this association is going between have their primary keys defined correctly in the EDMX.  What do I need to do to add this association in the EDMX?

Comment: Have you recently "Generated Database From Model"? some mappings don't seem to update until you do that (very annoying).

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  If I add the view into the EDMX, then it just creates a new Entity named CourseCompany1.

Comment: So to be clear, you created an association between two existing tables, set both their multiplicities to *, and then renamed the navigation property. You then ran the SQL generation tool (by running "Generate Database From Model" and are still seeing the above error?

Comment: I have no idea, I resolve mapping issues by (1) recreating the association/table in question, and (2) by running the SQL generation tool. Sorry I am not more help. I will post if I think of something though.

Comment: Sorry, but I saw "Generate Database From Model", and I thought it was "Update Model From Database".  Running the Generate command does fix it.  Put in an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, my comments in answer form below.

Comment: +1 for a researched attempt and working with me to find the problem.

Comment: Sorry again, but what happened that was something I did deleted the Store model in the EDMX, which allowed it to compile, but it threw errors when I actually ran it.  It was the end of the day and I didn't test it.  I did however determine how to fix it.

Comment: Glad you got your problem fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps to resolve this problem:

1. Add the many-to-many view through the "Update Model from Database" tool.
2. Edit the newly added entity so that both fields have Entity Key set to true.
3. Add an Association to the EDMX and configure it as I noted in the question above.
4. Click on the Association link and go to the Mapping Details tab.
5. Select the view name in the Maps to dropdown and set the field mappings as well.
6. Delete the entity that was added in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error is often caused by not running the "Generate Database From Model" command (accessible from the context menu of the EDMX designer) after making changes to the design.

Running the tool (if it worked, it will update the SQL generation script) should cause the problem to go away.